# How can i show salary values with button from a table using DataTables?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm looking for documentation of this button below feature at  **[DataTables](https://datatables.net/)** website and i can't find that. Do you guys know something about?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you want this [Child Rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) example.

Comment: @andrewjames it's exactly what i was looking for, thanks!